# I've never had vs. not once have I had

Tags: sentence-meaning, subject-auxiliary-inversion

This is a *sentence meaning* question:

> Sentence #1: I've been running this extension for over a month, and **not once have I had** a serious problem. (From an internet source)

Vs.

> Sentence #2: I've been running this extension for over a month, and **I have never had** a serious problem. (My construction)

As an ESL, sentence1 is uncommon. Do the two sentences above mean the same?

Comment: Yes, they mean the same thing exactly. But the first is a more **emphatic** construction. Not once [etc.] is stronger than: I have never had an x.

Comment: Is the sentence1 only good for speaking? Is it formal or casual type?

Comment: Google for "subject-auxiliary inversion" or "emphasis subject-auxiliary inversion", and **so much info will you find** that it will improve your understanding. (0: Therefore did I add the tag to your question.